# Removing Duplicate Custom Taxonomy Terms from within a Dropdown Select?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type that includes a custom taxonomy, called `client_name`. There is a page that loads these custom post types and displays them. What I need to develop is a dropdown list that displays all the custom taxonomy of those custom posts, which I have done, but I need to remove duplicates, and arrange them alphabetically, which is where I am having problems.

This is what I am trying for removing duplicates (it doesn't work):

```
<?php
<form method="post" id="clientform" action="" onsubmit="return getURL(this.url.value)">
  <select name="url" id="client">
    <option selected="selected">By Client</option>
    <?php
      $args=array(    
        'post_type' => 'our_work',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
      );
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
      $k=0;
      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
          $termArray[$k] = array (trim(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'client_name')));
          // $text = trim(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'client_name'));
          for ($i = 0; $i <= $termArray.count; $i++ ) {    
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $tempArray.count; $j++) {
              if ($tempArray[$i] == $tempArray[$j]) {        
                unset($tempArray[$k]); 
                $termArray = array_values($termArray);
              }
            } // end of for 
            $k++; 
        ?><option value="<?php bloginfo('url'); echo "/client_name/"; echo $termArray[$k]; ?>"><?php echo $termArray[$k]; ?></option><?php 
        } ?>    
        <?php 
        endwhile; 
      } 
      wp_reset_query(); 
    ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" id="clientsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Ok, now I ran across this PHP function the other day and it does what I want, I just dont know how to use it correctly.

> `array_unique($input);`

Help me out guys ....
Note the code listed above is only one code branch I was trying, not the whole file.

---

### UPDATE

Hey this does help me quite a bit, it and I found this to use, this gets me like 95% done, but not 100% yet. I tried your code, and I tried this one I am using, and it removes the dup's but anything that comes after it wont display hmm....

Heres the WP code:

```
<?php
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $termArray[$i] = trim(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'client_name'));
    $termArray = array_unique($termArray);
    $termArray = array_values($termArray);
    print_r($termArray);  
    print_r(sizeof($termArray));
    if ($termArray[$i] != '') { 
      ?><option value="<?php bloginfo('url'); echo "/client_name/"; echo $termArray[$i]; ?>"><?php echo $termArray[$i]; ?></option><?php 
    }// end of if $i++; 
  endwhile; 
} 
wp_reset_query();
```

And here is the output from the array, it duplicates the array output because it is called every time a new post is called within the loop. The page is available here:

> [`http://magicvideo.com/cms/work/`](http://magicvideo.com/cms/work/)

View the source to see what i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@Hunter Brelsford:**

Good to see you here over from the [WordPress Group on LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?mostPopular=&gid=154024).

Maybe I misunderstand your question but it sounds like you are **simply trying to get rid of dups in an array?** For example, let's say you have an array clients:

```
<?php
$clients = array(
  'Jones Construction',
  'Smith Wholesale',
  'Smith Wholesale',
  'Williams Dry Cleaning'
);
```

And you want to convert to an array like this?

```
<?php
$clients = array(
  'Jones Construction',
  'Smith Wholesale',
  'Williams Dry Cleaning'
);
```

(*If yes, that's a PHP question and not a WordPress question, normally something [we send away](http://stackoverflow.com), but I'll go ahead and answer here anyway.*)

Tis easy; since array keys are unique in PHP just flip the array (exchange the values with their keys) then return the array keys and you'll have your unique array, like so:

```
<?php
$clients = array(
  'Jones Construction',
  'Smith Wholesale',
  'Smith Wholesale',
  'Williams Dry Cleaning'
);
print_r(array_keys(array_flip($clients)));
```

That code prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Jones Construction
    [1] => Smith Wholesale
    [2] => Williams Dry Cleaning
)
```

Was that what you were after?

### UPDATE:

Hi **@Hunter Brelsford**:

I'm responding to your update. Okay, why don't we try and tackle this a different way? Here's a standalone example you can copy to the root of your website as `test.php` and then run it as [`http://magicvideo.com/test.php`](http://magicvideo.com/test.php) to see it work:

```
<?php
include "wp-load.php";
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
global $wpdb;
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT DISTINCT
  tt.term_id
FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND p.post_status='publish'
  AND p.post_type='our_work'
  AND tt.taxonomy='client_name'
SQL;
$terms = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
$term_ids = array();
foreach($terms as $term) {
  $term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
}
$terms = get_terms('client_name',array(
  'include'=> implode(',',$term_ids),
));
print_r($terms);
```

We use raw SQL to query the terms in the `taxonomy='client_name'` for `'post_type='our_work'` and then we collect the `$term->term_id`s to filter the list of taxonomy terms. I used raw SQL because WordPress doesn't provide a good way to get this data through an API, at least not that I could find on short notice (*if someone else knows of a better way via the API that doesn't require loading a lot more data than necessary please let me know*).

Hopefully this will suggest an approach so that you'll be able to use this code in your example? Let me know if know if not.